# Altbeacon scan period requirements for latest version ( 2.15.4 )

Tags: altbeacon

I have read a lot of information regarding the foreground/background scan periods and issues for long scans on Android 7 but I am confused as to what should be configured for best results in the latest alt-beacon library ( 2.15.4 ).

We have implemented a foreground service and bootstrapping and require the library to do the following:

App in Foreground scan for 1100ms, sleep 0 ms

App in Background scan and 1100ms, sleep 10000ms

We are aware that there will be edge cases when beacons are not detected due to start/stop scanning but would prefer this over the potential of the app scanning being killed by the OS due to long running scans.

What setForeground... setBackground... values should be used for the above requirements? OR should we not use these methods and just use the defaults?

Will this cause the "Scanning to frequently" issue and how would we get around this with settings as close as possible to our requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scan rates you describe will work on most phones by doing this:

```
 beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100); // Default, so this line not needed
 beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0); // Default, so this line not needed
 beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
 beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000);
 BackgroundPowerSaver bps = new BackgroundPowerSaver();
```

However, on Android 8+, time between scans will be throttled to about ~15 minutes by the operating system.  If you cannot accept this, then the only alternative is to instruct the library to use a  [foreground service](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html).  If you do configure a foreground service, then you can get that exact background rate of scanning you want even on Android 8+.

I say this works on "most phones" because big Chinese manufacturers (e.g. Huawei, OnePlus, Xiaomi ) have started forking their Android versions starting in late 2017 to implement aggressive power saving features that block beacon scanning in the background.  The proprietary forks either block scanning when the screen is off (Huawei see [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/778) and [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554)) (Xiaomi see [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/643)) or block foreground services (OnePlus see [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/806)).  These effectively break Android apps from working properly on their operating system forks.

Comment: Thanks David, so given I have implemented a foreground service, when the app is in the background do  beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100); and beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000); take effect ?

Comment: The background scan rates only take effect if you are using the BackgroundPowerSaver class, and background is defined as whenever no activity is in the foreground with the screen unlocked.  If you don't use the BackgroundPowerSaver class, the library will always be in foreground mode unless you manually make an API call to put it in background mode.